# In Jodit editor trying to allow highlighting but no changes to actually text

Tags: reactjs, highlight, readonly, jodit

I want to allow highlighting but not all the user to change the underlying text in Jodit-react.
If I do readonly this doesn't allow the highlighting.
Any suggestions?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: That is what I am looking for is a code example to allow highlighting but not allow text changes